# (Excel) How to search if a range of numbers is contained in an interval of numbers

Tags: excel

This shouldn't be too complicated. On Excel I have 2 columns:

- Start date - 21
- End date - 23

(21 and 23 are examples, but that is how the data is displayed - I have a week number for start date and a week number for end date)

Then I have, on the same row, a series of columns with numbers - 13, 17, 22, for example.

I want to check if any of these numbers is contained in the interval between Start Date and End Date.

In this example, the formula would say that 22 is indeed included in the interval between 21 and 23.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not fully clear how your sheet looks or what you want, but if I got you right, then you need a formula like this:

```
=OR((A2<=D2:K2)*(B2>=D2:K2))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

At a sheet like this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Dirk :)